# Find the limit sup and limit inf of a given sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose we have a set $X_b = \{\frac{a}{b}:a \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}\} $ where $b \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$. We want to find $\lim_{b \to +\infty} \inf{X_b}$ and also find 
find $\lim_{b \to +\infty} \sup{X_b}$.

Attempt: Clearly as $b \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{a}{b} \rightarrow 0$ therefore the sequence inside $X_b$ will tend to $0$ faster as b gets larger. We also see this sequence is not monotone since its cannot be a sequence of subsets. By definition we know that:

$\lim_{b \to +\infty} \inf{X_b} = \bigcup _{b=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{i=b}^{\infty}X_i$

$\lim_{b \to +\infty} \sup{X_b} = \bigcap _{b=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{i=b}^{\infty}X_i$

To get a better picture we can see that:
$X_1$ = $\{1,2,3,...\} = \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ , $X_2$ = $\{1/2,1,3/2,2,...\}$ so we can see that $X_1 \subset X_2$. Lets look at $X_3$ = $\{1/3,2/3,1,4/3,...\}$ but here $X_2$ not subset of $X_3$. Noticing this pattern we see that $\forall b \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$, 
{b/b,2b/b,3b/b,...} $\subset$ $X_b$. From this I want to conclude $\bigcap_{i=b}^{\infty}X_i = \mathbb{Z^{+}}, b \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$. If we can prove this, then from that could we conclude 
$\lim_{b \to +\infty} \inf{X_b} = \bigcup _{b=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{i=b}^{\infty}X_i = \mathbb{Z^{+}}?$

Comment: In those last two equations, you have used the notation $A_i$, which you have not defined.

Comment: @GerryMyerson edited question, thanks.

Comment: @GerryMyerson does the question make more sense after the edit?

Comment: The two expressions $\bigcap_{i=b}^{\infty}X_i$ and 
$\bigcup_{i=b}^{\infty}X_i$ appear in the definitions. Are you able to identify these sets (which depend on $b$)?

Comment: @GregMartin I notice that when b = 1, then the intersections of $X_i$ should be all the positive integers. Intuitively thinking about it, for all b this seems to be true (since for all b, we will have b/b,2b/b, 3b/b, 4b/b in the set). For the unions it seems like we will get all the positive rational numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $m|n \Rightarrow X_m \subseteq X_n$. Hence we see $X_1 \subseteq X_n$ for all $n$ and so $S_b =\bigcap_{i=b}^{\infty}X_i \supseteq X_1 = \Bbb Z^+$. For the reverse inclusion suppose ${m \over n} \in S_b$, $(m,n)=1$, $n \gt 1$. Choose $p$ prime with $p \gt n,b$ then ${m \over n} \notin X_p \supseteq S_b$, contradiction.  
  
For the other part we use $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i= \Bbb Q^+ $ (this is easy to prove) and $X_n \subseteq X_{nb}$ to find for all $b$: $$\bigcup_{i=b}^{\infty}X_i= \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i= \Bbb Q^+$$

Comment: So what I was guessing is indeed correct! So in that case, would the final answers be that for the inf limit we get $Z^{+}$ and the sup limit $Q^{+}$?

Comment: Yes, because $\bigcup_{b=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{i=b}^{\infty} X_i = \bigcup_{b=1}^{\infty} \Bbb Z^+ = \Bbb Z^+$ and $\bigcap_{b=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{i=b}^{\infty} X_i = \bigcap_{b=1}^{\infty} \Bbb Q^+ = \Bbb Q^+$.

Comment: Great! Thank you, this helped make my original answer more formal.